# UIImagePickerController didFinishPickingImage returning incorrect imageOrientation

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using `UImagePickerController` for capturing images from camera.

In `didFinishPickingImage` delegate method i am getting images with incorrect `imageOrientation`.

For an example when i am taking a picture in portrait mode i am getting back the correct image but `imageOrientation = RIGHT` (rawValue = 3) instead of `imageOrientation = UP`.

When i take a picture in landscape mode i get the correct image back but again incorrect `imageOrientation = DOWN`.

As you can see from the code i am checking the orientation of the image as soon as i get it from the picker.

```
override func viewDidLoad() 
{
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        presentViewController(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) 
{
    print("orientation: \(image.imageOrientation.rawValue)")
}
```

Contrary to other similar questions i am getting the correct image back but `imageOrientation` is always incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem. use this function to resolve:

```
func fixImageOrientation(src:UIImage)->UIImage {

if src.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Up {
    return src
}

var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

switch src.imageOrientation {
case UIImageOrientation.Down, UIImageOrientation.DownMirrored:
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, src.size.width, src.size.height)
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI))
    break
case UIImageOrientation.Left, UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored:
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, src.size.width, 0)
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
    break
case UIImageOrientation.Right, UIImageOrientation.RightMirrored:
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, src.size.height)
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
    break
case UIImageOrientation.Up, UIImageOrientation.UpMirrored:
    break
}

switch src.imageOrientation {
case UIImageOrientation.UpMirrored, UIImageOrientation.DownMirrored:
    CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, src.size.width, 0)
    CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
    break
case UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored, UIImageOrientation.RightMirrored:
    CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, src.size.height, 0)
    CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
case UIImageOrientation.Up, UIImageOrientation.Down, UIImageOrientation.Left, UIImageOrientation.Right:
    break
}

let ctx:CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(src.size.width), Int(src.size.height), CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(src.CGImage), 0, CGImageGetColorSpace(src.CGImage), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)!

CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform)

switch src.imageOrientation {
case UIImageOrientation.Left, UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored, UIImageOrientation.Right, UIImageOrientation.RightMirrored:
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, src.size.height, src.size.width), src.CGImage)
    break
default:
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, src.size.width, src.size.height), src.CGImage)
    break
}

let cgimg:CGImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx)!
let img:UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)

return img
}
```

Comment: I don’t think this is the right solution because as i said the image is already rotated correctly only metadata (imageOrientation) is incorrect.